# PHP Menu Items Count then add under more button

Tags: php, button, menu, items

I use the bellow code to load the main menu elements from some CMS, the present code is perfect except that it loads ALL the main items on a single line of menu - which will make the width of it unusable in any centered design (under 1000px).. I want to change this script so after 15 main elements will add a "MORE" button under which the rest of the main menu items will show as sub-items of this "MORE" button (they will not have their own sub-items as the first 15 do).. How can I do it? 
Thanks!

```
        <?php 

require_once( '../../../inc/header.inc.php' );
require_once( DIRECTORY_PATH_INC . 'membership_levels.inc.php' );
require_once( DIRECTORY_PATH_ROOT . "templates/tmpl_{$tmpl}/scripts/TemplMenu.php" );

            class SimpleMenu extends TemplMenu
            {
            function getCode()
            {
            $this->iElementsCntInLine = 100;
            $this->getMenuInfo();
            $this->genTopItems();
            return $this->sCode;
            }

            function genTopItem($sText, $sLink, $sTarget, $sOnclick, $bActive, $iItemID, $isBold = false, $sPicture = '')
            {
            $sActiveStyle = ($bActive) ? ' id="tm_active"' : '';

            if (!$bActive) {
            $sAlt= $sOnclick ? ( ' alt="' . $sOnclick . '"' ) : '';
            $sTarget  = $sTarget  ? ( ' target="_parent"' ) : '';
            }

            $sLink = (strpos($sLink, 'http://') === false && !strlen($sOnclick)) ? $this->sSiteUrl . $sLink : $sLink;

            $sSubMenu = $this->getAllSubMenus($iItemID);

            $sImgTabStyle = $sPictureRep = '';
            if ($isBold && $sPicture != '') {
            $sPicturePath = getTemplateIcon($sPicture);
            $sPictureRep = "<img src='{$sPicturePath}' style='vertical-align:middle;width:16px;height:16px;' />";
            $sText = '&nbsp;';
            $sImgTabStyle = 'style="width:38px;"';
            }

            $sMainSubs = ($sSubMenu=='') ? '' : " {$sSubMenu} </a>";
            $this->sCode .= "

               <li><a href='{$sLink}' {$sOnclick} target='_parent'>{$sPictureRep}{$sText}</a>
                <div id='submenu'>
                <ul>
                 <li>{$sMainSubs}</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
               </li>
            ";
            }
            }

            $objMenu = new SimpleMenu();
            echo "<ul id='ddmenu'>";
            echo $objMenu->getCode();
            echo "</ul>";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd use CSS and Javascript (+jQuery) to do this.

Use Javascript to find any `li`s within `ul#ddmenu` that have an index of 15 or more, and give them a different class. Then, add your "More" button, and use onclick/hover etc to display the remaining `li`s.